# How can I compute $\sqrt 5$ to 200 places in base 40 arithmetic

Tags: numerics, education

What code should I write to compute $\sqrt{5_{40}}$ to 200 places in base 40 digits.

Comment: You can do `RealDigits[Sqrt[5], 40, 200]`, but how do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Thank you. I would like it to be in an expanded form of digits like 3.14159.

Comment: What do you want to use for digits 10 through 39?

Comment: @CarlWoll Sorry not sure I quite understand. I am helping a friend on a project. He said he needed the expanded form of sqrt(5) base 40 to 200 places.

Comment: Maybe your friend should be asking the question, then.

Comment: He's an older fellow not good with the computer. I think the way it is set up with real digits will work. Is there any way to remove the comma in between every two numbers? also what is the ,1} at the end representing?

Comment: The 1 as the end is the number of those digits to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: Why $\sqrt{5_{40}}$ instead of $\sqrt{5}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat similar to Mark Adler's:

```
Row[Insert[
    MapIndexed[Style[#, {Black, Red}[[Mod[First@#2, 2, 1]]]] &, 
     Row /@ PadLeft[IntegerDigits /@ First@#, {Automatic, 2}]], ".", 
    Last@# + 1] &@RealDigits[Sqrt[5], 40, 200], "\[VeryThinSpace]"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very pretty. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
StringJoin[Insert[IntegerString[#[[1]], 10, 2], ".", #[[2]] + 1]] &@
 RealDigits[Sqrt[5], 40, 200]
```

> ```
> "02.091728140035332224343211090932151625142013120825361923310831051807\
> 3421001608191731102219000410212617223624222600122708203331043608362812\
> 3631333328293708151714153919062026380325301636293529103922120718042439\
> 2730012518161424151608201000360107363326070730111205013135003604102822\
> 2702382819043930011101283836150039101722123630012505230627071638250012\
> 1109392123131817193922111718101939361628132803363515"
> ```